# Sticky footer problems

Tags: html, css

I have read a lot on google and here and I can't find a solution, I don't get it why do I get the scroll bar and I need to scroll down in order to see the footer, at this moment I don't have any content and it's not necesary to scroll down, as you can see here: [URL REMOVED], If I remove `margin-top` fro the logo than it works, but I need that `margin-top` there.Can you guys help me please to find a solution.

Best Regards.

Comment: Try to give some basic structure of the page in html and some css next time. It'll increase the number of answers and their general quality.

Comment: i dont get it.. why is `body` some pixels away form top.. (there is no margin/padding anywhere)

Comment: @Achshar There's a margin-top on the logo.

Comment: didn't see that one coming :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gave `body` a height of 100% and `#wrap` a min-height of 100%, so the footer is pushed outside of the viewwindow (which is what 100% height is). Try removing or lowering the value of min-height on `#wrap` and the footer will come up.

**Edit:**
If you're going to use the css from the page you linked, you can't add any vertical margin, padding or borders on anything. You are doing this on `#logo` and that's what's messing things up.

It seems you're doing this because you want the content to have a certain background, but you don't want this behind the logo. You can solve this by adding another div inside `#wrap` that wraps the content and give this the background. Leave the header white.

Summary:

- Remove the margin-top on `#logo`.
- Change the margin-bottom on `#wrap` to -54px.
- Add a div for the content within `#wrap` for the background.

That should solve your problem.

Comment: If I remove the min height the footer will jump up to the header, what I want it's to stay to the bottom and have the scroll window only when truly needed

Comment: Why can't it just be at the bottom of the content, like a footer? Does it really need to be the bottom of the view window? That's going to be really hard. Just add it to #wrap and have it be pushed down by the content.

Comment: Yes it needs to be at the bottom of the view window :D check this page out http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ this is what I'm using

Comment: and maybe an `overflow:auto` on `html`?